# Zabbix Trigger based on last 3 data polls

Tags: zabbix

I am having trouble setting up a Zabbix trigger for a Windows server.

The goal is to use run netstat via the Zabbix item, and count the number of entries with 'TIME WAIT'.

However, I don't want the trigger to alert when it the past 3 runs have data (a value more than 0)

I have tried using 'count(#3)>0' and 'last(#3)>0' but it always seems to fire when the item update happens, not based on the last three polls.

Should I be using a different expression?

Answer (score 1):

To check for the last 3 values being 0 (or negative, but probably not possible in your case), use `max(#3)=0`.